# Second group cohomology $H^2(U(1),\mathbf{Z}_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The extension of $U(1)$ by $\mathbf{Z}_n$ is classified by $H^2(U(1),\mathbf{Z}_n)$.
What's the second group cohomology $H^2(U(1),\mathbf{Z}_n)$?

Comment: Are you taling about the cohomology of discrete groups here?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez My goal is to classify the extension. It seems to me that some people use differentiable cohomology or Borel cohomology. Then for finite Abelian $Z_n$, they identify $H^2(U(1), Z_n)$ with $H^2(BU(1), Z_n)$. May I know if there is a problem here?

Comment: Well, you can view a Lie group as a Lie group and as a discrete group, and the various cohomolgies do not generally agree — there is a famous conjecture of Milnor and Friedlander on the subject, for example.

Comment: Differentiable cohomology with values in a discrete group is not very interesting, as a smooth cocycle with values on a discrete group is constant.

Comment: You have a covering $\mathbb R\to U(1)$, and $\mathbb Q$ acts on the group $\mathbb R$ by isomorphisms, so $H^*(\mathbb R_{\text{discrete}},G)$ is a rational vector space. If G is torsion, then that cohomology has to be zero. Use now a spectral sequence to compute $H^*(U(1),G)$ from the extension $Z\to R\to U(1)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you. May I ask if $H^2(U(1),Z_n)$ is isomorphic to $Z_n$?